# Access to the nginx files from the broken Docker image

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile, devops, docker-swarm

How can I extract the data from the nginx.conf and default.conf files if the image does not run. I tried with volumes but it shows that the file is empty.The image is this obur5/nginx-broken-image:latest

[When I run image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqnQ0.png)

[Ween I open the files through docker desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sisG9.png)

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration

/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/

/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh

10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version

/docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh

/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh

/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh

/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up

2023/11/13 07:52:40 [emerg] 1#1: no "events" section in configuration

nginx: [emerg] no "events" section in configuration
```

Comment: Why not check **why** that image won't run and fix that? Can you share more details, like an error message? Please share all such details **in text form**

Comment: I can replace those configurations with others. But I definitely need the ones that were in the images

Comment: The files have been overwritten in the image, so you need to read the contents of the files from an earlier layer. You can see the layers using `docker history obur5/nginx-broken-image:latest`. The `dive` tool can help you with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the files from a docker image you can do something like this:

```bash
docker cp $(docker container create <image>):/ rootfs
```

This should extract the entire filesystem into a folder called "rootfs"

Comment: Thank you, I extracted the data.  It may be that the files to configure are without data and read, write and execute rights for all users?

Comment: That looks at the current contents of the image. As I understand it, OP needs to retrieve a file that existed in the early layers of the image but has been overwritten in a later layer. It looks like a school assignment in a docker security class to me.

Comment: Well if thats the case... fetching and untaring individual layers does not sound like a fun afternoon.

Comment: Yes it is, but how can I solve this?